# Chain rule help? Property check

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $\lambda = Df(a)$ where $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, then

$$\begin{align}
D(\lambda^{-1} \circ f)(a) &= D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a)) \circ Df(a) \\
&= \lambda^{-1}\circ Df(a)
\end{align}$$

Can someone explain the last line to me? Also, since we are dealing with matrices, the composition can be regarded as multiplication.

I tried $$f = (x + y,y)$$, which is linear and

$$\lambda = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
 0&1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

So $\lambda^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
 0&-1 
\end{bmatrix}$

But now I don't know how to find $D(\lambda^{-1})$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a linear map is the matrix which defines it, so it is constant.

Comment: I don't see how $D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a)) = \lambda^{-1}$

Comment: is $\lambda$ a matrix square matrix?

Comment: Yes, since $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: but, is it non-singular?

Comment: Yes, $\lambda$ is non singular

Comment: you've gotta convince yourself that the derivative of a linear map is constant.. make an example

Comment: What is the constant you are talking about? $\lambda$?

Comment: yes, constant matrix, $\lambda=Df(a)$, right?

Comment: OKay, but what does that have to do with relating to the LHS $D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a))$

Comment: since $D(\lambda^{-1})=\lambda^{-1}$

Comment: It isn't $I$? Why $D(\lambda^{-1}) = \lambda^{-1}$

Comment: i insist, look at a derivative of a linear map, a simple example

Comment: Please see update

Comment: one uses a matrix $A$ to map $v\to Av$.. in your case use $v=(x,y)$ and $A=\lambda^{-1}$ to see the effect on derivative $D(\lambda^{-1})$

Comment: Is $f(a) = v$ in my case?

Comment: yes, it could be, but my friend i gotta go to sleep, see you

Comment: What do you mean "could be"?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a linear map is itself.  Consider $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $x\mapsto Ax$, by matrix multiplication.  Then the derivative of $A$ at the point $x$, is the unique linear map $D_xA:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ so that
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{||A(x+h)-Ax-(D_xA)h||}{||h||}=0,$$
but it's easily seen (by linearity) that $A$ itself satisfies this.